# Jenkins post build task unable to run script

Tags: bash, jenkins

I have simple bash script `script.sh` in my `/home/ubuntu/jenkins/workspace` folder. This bash script runs -

```
cd /home/ubuntu/tools; /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/ruby script.rb
```

In this ruby script I have several environment variable for API keys and it looks to be where the script is having issues with. Here is the error message I'm receiving from jenkins when the post build task runs -

```
Performing Post build task...
Match found for : : True
Logical operation result is TRUE
Running script  : /home/ubuntu/jenkins/workspace/script.sh
[Ansible-Deploy] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins3728886043127394122.sh
+ /home/ubuntu/jenkins/workspace/script.sh
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/graphql-1.7.13/lib/graphql/schema/loader.rb:16:in `fetch': key not found: "data" (KeyError)
  from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/graphql-1.7.13/lib/graphql/schema/loader.rb:16:in `load'
  from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/graphql-client-0.12.2/lib/graphql/client.rb:52:in `load_schema'
  from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/graphql-client-0.12.2/lib/graphql/client.rb:60:in `load_schema'
  from /home/ubuntu/tools/script.rb:274:in `<module:Github>'
  from /home/ubuntu/tools/script.rb:264:in `<main>'
POST BUILD TASK : FAILURE
END OF POST BUILD TASK : 0
```

And in that script.rb file around line 264 -

```
GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN = ENV['GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN']

...

module Github
  HttpAdapter ||= GraphQL::Client::HTTP.new(URL) do
    def headers(context)
      {
        "Authorization" => "Bearer #{GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN}",
        "User-Agent" => 'Ruby'
      }
    end
  end

  Schema ||= GraphQL::Client.load_schema(HttpAdapter)
  Client ||= GraphQL::Client.new(schema: Schema, execute: HttpAdapter)
end
```

Important to note that either running the bash script or ruby script while ssh'd in works fine, its only fails when run from the jenkins post build task.

Comment: where are you running your jenkins?? in the cloud or in your local??? If it is in the cloud, then make all your required env variables are there. Please mention which is the 264 line number content??? or else update the whole line numbers in your code..